# YAML formatting error for Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a crontab that is supposed to deploy a crontab remotely. But seems like it is complaining about some syntax error.

Ansible playbook is :

```
---
- hosts: cac
  tasks:
#  - name: Deploy cron to GZIP old log/out files.
   - cron:
       name: "Cron entry to gzip rotated log/out files."
       minute: "0"
       hour: "*"
       job: "find /opt/app/log/ -maxdepth 1 \( -name "*out.*[0-9]" -o -name "*.log.[0-9]" \) -type f -size +100M -exec tar -czf {}.tar.gz {} \;"
       state: present
       disabled: yes
```

Error I am getting is :

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/home/ansible/playbooks/deploy_cac_cron.yaml': line 9, column 69, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

       hour: "*"
       job: 'find /opt/app/log/ -maxdepth 1  -name '*out.*[0-9]' -o -name '*.log.[0-9]'  -type f -size +100M -exec tar -czf {}.tar.gz {} \; '
                                                                    ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes.  If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes.  For instance this arbitrary
example:

    foo: "bad" "wolf"

Could be written as:

    foo: '"bad" "wolf"'
```

Looks like it is mixing up the job that I am sending. Any ideas what I can do here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to backslash the double quotes (") within the outer double quotes to tell the compiler that they are meant to be part of a command, otherwise as soon as the compiler sees next " it will assume it as end of command hence making the rest of the statement invalid.

Also, I don't think you need to backslash the brackets.

Here is a working yaml for me.

```
- name: Stackoverflow
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - cron:
        name: "Cron entry to gzip rotated log/out files."
        minute: "0"
        hour: "*"
        job: "find /opt/app/log/ -maxdepth 1 ( -name \"*out.*[0-9]\" -o -name \"*.log.[0-9]\" ) -type f -size +100M -exec tar -czf {}.tar.gz {} ;"
        state: present
        disabled: yes
```

**Output:**

```
tigerroarz@tigerroarz-Latitude-E6520:~/work/feature/so-playground$ ansible-playbook site.yml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [Stackoverflow] ***********************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [cron] ********************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 0):

you've mixed quoting

```
       job: "find /opt/app/log/ -maxdepth 1 \( -name '*out.*[0-9]' -o -name '*.log.[0-9]' \) -type f -size +100M -exec tar -czf {}.tar.gz {} \;"
```

this should be better

Comment: I tried this. But it doesnt work. the answer given by Samuel worked. Thanks.